Purpose of Multiple Passes in the FFT
I am currently working on implementing a version of Jerry Tessendorf's Ocean waves, and right now, I'm dealing with the inverse FFT. I wanted to implement the algorithm on my own to try to gain an understanding, and I opted to do so on the GPU since that is where the data will be read by the vertex shader. Therefore, I'm using a compute shader to perform the calculation.
My understanding is that when the FFT is performed on the GPU, it is done in either a fragment shader or in a compute shader. When performed in a fragment shader, I can understand how each "combination" step requires a new pass. However, I fail to see the reason why this may need to be the case for compute shaders, as threadgroups can be synced within the shader, so long as our FFT is smaller than the maximum size of a workgroup.
I wanted to try to implement the FFT in a single pass, so I wrote some code to do it. I was inspired by the bitonic merge sort algorithm presented in this article. After reading this article, I attempted to implement a crude FFT over a small SSBO, and it worked!
Here is the code.
#version 450 core

#define SIZE 8
#define LOG_SIZE int(log2(SIZE))
#define NUM_CACHES 2
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384

shared vec2 cache[SIZE][NUM_CACHES];

layout (binding = 0) buffer ssbo
{
    vec2 data[SIZE];
};

uint reverseBits(uint num, uint numBits)
{
    uint value = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i < numBits; i++)
    {
        value <<= 1;
        value |= (num & 1);
        num >>= 1;
    }

    return value;
}

uvec3 fft(uint thread, uint cacheIndex, uint evenIndex, uint oddIndex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LOG_SIZE; i++) // each iteration represents a combination of stages
    {
        // ensure that all threads have finished the last iteration
        barrier(); 

        // calculate our new even and odd indices
        // 1) use one thread per set of even and odd indices
        // 2) each dft requires half its size worth of threads => dft # is (thread div halfSize)
        // 3) even index = dftNum * dftSize + (thread mod halfSize)
        // 4) odd index = evenIndex + halfSize
        uint halfSize = 1u << i;
        uint fullSize = halfSize << 1;
        int dftNum = int(thread) / int(halfSize);
        int dftElement = int(thread) % int(halfSize);
        evenIndex = dftNum * int(fullSize) + dftElement;
        oddIndex = evenIndex + int(halfSize);

        // compute the twiddle factor for combining two dfts
        float twiddleAngle = -2.0 * M_PI * dftElement / fullSize; // making this positive causes iFFT
        vec2 twiddle = vec2(cos(twiddleAngle), sin(twiddleAngle));

        // retrieve our values and twiddle the odd factor
        vec2 even = cache[cacheIndex][evenIndex];
        vec2 odd = cache[cacheIndex][oddIndex];

        odd = vec2(odd.x * twiddle.x - odd.y * twiddle.y,
                   odd.x * twiddle.y + odd.y * twiddle.x);
                
        // move to the next ping pong buffer and combine
        cacheIndex = (cacheIndex + 1) % NUM_CACHES;
        cache[cacheIndex][evenIndex] = even + odd;
        cache[cacheIndex][oddIndex] = even - odd;
    }

    return uvec3(cacheIndex, evenIndex, oddIndex);
}

layout (local_size_x = SIZE/2) in;
void main()
{
    // each thread is responsible for one even index and one odd index
    uint thread = uint(gl_LocalInvocationID.x);
    uint cacheIndex = 0;
    uint evenIndex = thread * 2;
    uint oddIndex = evenIndex + 1;

    // copy from our buffer to the cache in bit reversal order
    cache[cacheIndex][evenIndex] = data[reverseBits(evenIndex, LOG_SIZE)];
    cache[cacheIndex][oddIndex] = data[reverseBits(oddIndex, LOG_SIZE)];
    
    // perform the fft
    uvec3 indices = fft(thread, cacheIndex, evenIndex, oddIndex);
    cacheIndex = indices.x;
    evenIndex = indices.y;
    oddIndex = indices.z;

    // copy our data back into the ssbo
    data[evenIndex] = cache[cacheIndex][evenIndex];
    data[oddIndex] = cache[cacheIndex][oddIndex];
}

The algorithm works, and I believe it should scale to buffers of 1024 samples, however, I only tested modest sizes. Now for my confusion. Why isn't this approach taken in more contexts? Here are some other things that I am thinking about, as I've also implemented a two pass version of this algortihm to take the 2D FFT of a texture:

Synchronizing a threadgroup is more expensive than a new pass
Other implementations require much larger FFTs.
There is a flaw with my understanding of synchronization
Precision can be gained via an alternative implementation (My results are strangely inconsistent in 2D FFT for large sizes)

Thank you in advance to anyone to who took the time to read this, and I sincerely appreciate your help!
